# Is that class instantiation method valid (from the both spec and implementation point of view) and future-proven?

Tags: php, class, factory-pattern

Experimenting with the language (not just for fun but for syntactically elegant way to implement ORM object factory) I've found occasionally it's possible to create new objects using given syntax:

```
$factory = new Factory();
$myBrandNewObject = new $factory->MagicallyExtractedField(true, 'sure');

class Factory {
  public function __get($name) {
    return ... ANY CLASS HERE ...
  }
}
```

Is it legal or not? I worry it may be just a hack that may break things in future.